# "Elasticity of marginal utility of consumption ( μ ) with respect to utility." (Green Book quote)?

Tags: utility

In the [Green Book](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/220541/green_book_complete.pdf) (page 97) it is stated "the elasticity of marginal utility of consumption (μ) with respect to utility".

What is it? Is it an error ? I always heard of the elasticity of the marginal utility with respect to consumption...

Comment: It is just an unnecessary (and apparently confusing) wording, that probably emerged because the author had already used the word "consumption" while he "remembered" that the concept description should end with a "with respect to..." It is the measure we all know, in any case, nothing fancy.

Answer (score 2):

Mere googling leads me to find a bunch of references about **elasticity of marginal utility**.

[Here](http://economics.mit.edu/files/7340) Professor Acemoglu defines the elasticity of marginal utility as the inverse of the intertemporal elasticity of substitution (pagg. 17-18).

[Here](https://www.quora.com/What-does-the-elasticity-of-marginal-utility-of-consumption-with-respect-to-utility-mean) you can find a question analogous to yours together with an answer explained in an easier way than Acemoglu's lecture.

If you are interested in something more empirical, have a look [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1475-5890.2005.00010.x/full): it is a paper by David Evans about the empirical estimation of elasticity of marginal utility in OECD countries.

Hope this is enough. If you have other questions, please ask

Comment: Actually the second link you posted on quora is.. _my answer_ !! The question is not on the elasticity of marginal utility itself but with the final part of the cited sentence "with respect with utility". I suspect (and this is why I did pose the question) that it should be "with respect with consumption" !!

Comment: It wasn't clear at all. Maybe you should edit your question to better specify the question